# React + Backbone - model is being deleted twice

Tags: javascript, cordova, rest, backbone.js, reactjs

I have a Backbone + React (in Flux) application that is attempting to delete the same record twice.

When I delete an item, my server responds accordingly and logs `DELETE: {Object...}`

It then tries again. My error callback in `Backbone.Model.destroy` logs:

```
response.status: 200
response.statusText: OK
response.responseText: <recordId>
```

From tracing it, it looks like the error occurs around the time that I'm in [ReactEventListener](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f46c631091db047e842cbfed6eb771737c97f9ba/src/renderers/dom/client/ReactEventListener.js).
The actual error occurs right after the finally [block](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f46c631091db047e842cbfed6eb771737c97f9ba/src/renderers/dom/client/ReactEventListener.js#L236) in `DispatchEvent`, [at this line in the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f46c631091db047e842cbfed6eb771737c97f9ba/src/renderers/dom/client/ReactEventListener.js#L238).

That is not to say that those lines of code are at fault, but I'm not sure how to properly debug this and figure out what is going wrong. It's strange that it breaks at no particular line of code - something running in the background maybe?

I noticed that if I set a break point at `TopLevelCallbackBookKeeping.release(bookKeeping)` and restart my app, I can't even add a record - it never calls my create function; just stops at the breakpoint and then game over. This may not be relevant not the problem, but may help in understanding what that function does. I, for one, am lost.

Has anyone had any experience with an issue like this, or can anyone give me insight into the cause of the problem?

#### Additional Info

1. I am using the [`Backbone.dualStorage` plugin](https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage) for syncing.
2. This is a mobile app (Phonegap).
3. My destroy function:

   ```js
   function destroy(todo) {
       todo.destroy({
           success: function(model, response) {
               console.log('SUCCESS: destroy(id) - ' + JSON.stringify(model));
           },
           error: function(model, reponse) {
               console.log('ERROR: destroy(id) - ' + JSON.stringify(model));
               console.log('\treponse status: ' + reponse.status);
               console.log('\treponse statusText: ' + reponse.statusText);
               console.log('\treponse reponseText: ' + reponse.responseText);
           }
       }); 
   }
   ```

**Edit:**
Looks like it's a bug in the plugin.